# aws lambda cron expression for 5 minutes before each hour

Tags: lambda, cron

Is it possible to define a cron expression to fire 5 minutes *before* each hour?

For every hour, I can use

```
cron(0 1 * * ? *)
```

but I need it to be 5 minutes prior to the hour...

Comment: the cron you pasted is for running at 01:00 every day, not every hour; anyway, isn't 5 minutes before each hour the same as 55 minutes after each hour? `55 * * * * *`

Comment: it's been a while since I've used cron - sorry. I'll give that a try!

Comment: @GUIDO - close - it worked with 55 * * * ? *

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create a rule in cloudwatch, you get a screen where you can enter an expression and it will evaluate it for you:

[image]